# ambiguous overload C++ for operator =

Tags: c++

```
for (dungeonLevel = 0; dungeonLevel < 5; dungeonLevel++)
{

    if (dungeonLevel = "1")
    {
        cout<< "You will be fighting the warrior Apollo";
        cout<< "Do you want to 1. attack 2. defend 3. dodge";
        if (turn = "1")
        {
            yourDamage = rand() % 5 + 0; //generates a number between 1 and 5

        }
```

This is producing a ambiguous error

[Error] ambiguous overload for '`operator=`' (operand types are '`std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}`' and '`int`')

I don't know a know anything about these errors. I hope you guys can give me a helping hand.

Thank you

Comment: `if (dungeonLevel = "1")` Surely you mean `==` here? (Same for the other if)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: `yourDamage = rand() % 5 + 0; //generates a number between 1 and 5`??

Comment: It's just saying that you can't assign an int to a string. yourDamage is a string variable presumably.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Where is `dungeonLevel` declared? It appears like you're using it as an `int` (`dungeonLevel = 0`) and also a `string` (dungeonLevel = "1"`)

Comment: yourDamage I was trying to get it to generate a number between 0 and 5 but hadn't been able to test that because of my error. I declared dungeonLevel as a string at the beginning of my code; how would I rewrite that so I can declare it properly?

Comment: You can't make `dungeonLevel` a string. I mean that would break your for loop if it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 if (dungeonLevel = "1")
```

This is the line causing the error. You want it to be:

```
 if (dungeonLevel == 1)
```

There are 2 changes I have made here:

**Firstly**, I replaced the `=` sign, called the assignment operator, with the `==` sign, which is the comparison operator. The assignment operator is used when you assign the variable on the left of the operator the value (could be a fixed value like 5, "hello", etc...). It does not make comparisons, as you are trying to do in your if-statement condition. Therefore, you need to use the comparison operator (`==`), which checks whether the statement on the left is the same as the statement on the right and passes on a Boolean value (true or false), depending on the results of the comparison, to tell the compiler whether to enter the if-statement's body or not. Therefore, you need to use the (`==`), not the (`=`) in your if-statement condition.

**Secondly**, I removed the apostrophes from the 1 in your if-statement condition, as you want an int value there, not string. When you run through a loop, you increment a counter, which has to be an `int` value.

---

**Another thing**:

```
for (dungeonLevel = 0; dungeonLevel < 5; dungeonLevel++)
```

In this line, you have not declared the data type of `dungeonLevel` (maybe you did this outside of the for-loop). It should be declared as type `int`.

Change your for-loop header to this:

```
for (int dungeonLevel = 0; dungeonLevel < 5; dungeonLevel++) // Notice that I added the data type of dungeonlevel in its initialization statement
```

Comment: Alright I changed that but I'm still getting the error would I need to change  string dungeonLevel= ""; to an int? Since I would be using a comparison operator and not using the double quotes?

Comment: `dungeonLevel`  must not be a string. Make it an integer.

Comment: Gimme a sec guys, I am editing my post to include the full error.

Comment: Just updated it to include all the errors I could catch.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: No problem. By the way, you should also change `rand() % 5 + 0` to `rand() % 5 + 1`, because `rand % 5` will give a number from 0 to 4, inclusive. To change that , you need to add one to it.